# Extracting user and group name from logs

Tags: regex

## Extracting user and group details

We have windows event logs with Group membership and user details.

We need to extract the Group and user details without the domain name details.

The issue is that some of the user or Group has domain details in the front, say ABC\user1 but some of them has no domain details included (Everyone)

I am adding regex101 here in order to understand the actual issue.

```
https://regex101.com/r/uArP6a/1 

Group\sMembership:\s+(([A-Za-z0-9-_]+\\)((?<test>[A-Za-z0-9-_ ]+))\s+)
```

Expected result need to be

- Domain Users
- Everyone
- Users
- NETWORK
- Authenticated Users
- This Organization
- FS-ABCDEFG-Workspaces_CS-Production-WIP_MODIFY
- FS-ABCDEFG-Workspaces_CS-EntertainmentDesign-WIP_READ
- FS-ABCDEFG-Wspaces_CS-Print-WIP_READ
- Workstations-Desktop-Add Remove
- FS-ABCDEFG-Wpaces_CS-Imagery-WIP_READ
- Authentication authority asserted identity
- APP-JDE-123

Your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of the `\G` anchor to assert the position at the end of the previous match and use a capturing group (or for example a named capturing group) to capture the group and user details.

```
(?:^Group Membership:|\G(?!^))\r?\n[\t ]*(?:[^\\\r\n]*\\)*(.+)
```

*About the pattern*

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `^Group Membership:` Match `Group Membership:` from the start of the string
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert position at the end of previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `\r?\n[\t ]*` Match newline and 0+ spaces or tabs (or `[\t ]+` for at least 1)
- `(?:[^\\\r\n]*\\)*` Repeat 0+ times matching not `\` or newline, then match a `\`
- `(.+)` Capture group, match any char except a newline 0+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/X2YAAd/1)

Answer (score 0):

`(?m)(?:^[ \t]*Group[ \t]*Membership:|(?!^)\G)\s*\r?\n\s*(?:(?!^\S).)+?\K([^\\\r\n]+?)(?=[ \t]*$)`

https://regex101.com/r/0J9Lie/1

```
 (?m)
 (?:
      ^ [ \t]* Group [ \t]* Membership:
   |  (?! ^ )
      \G
 )
 \s* \r? \n \s* 
 (?:
      (?! ^ \S )
      .
 )+?
 \K
 ( [^\\\r\n]+? )               # (1)
 (?= [ \t]* $ )
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your answer would be significantly improved by adding some text, not just code.

Comment: Thanks user11954145. For some reason, if there are no domain details before the user, say Everyone, first letter is missing "E" and only capturing other ones.